# How Can I Detect a valid url 200 with php?

Tags: php, validation, url

with php could find 404 pages, but I have some 200 return url as I validate url but not as invalidated them when they say something similar to say: "This file does not exist, the access to the Following file is limited or it has been removed due to Infringement of copyright. ", that I want to validate a page where some files are no longer available. Some examples:

1. http://depositfiles.org/files/r0flcxpwp
2. http://videozed.net/i31xn4fddoto

And my PHP code is:

```
$ch = curl_init("depositfiles.org/files/r0flcxpwp");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
curl_exec($ch);

$url_status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

if ("404" == $estatus_url) {
    echo "do something";`
}

curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: so what isn't working? (other than that rogue ` after your echo, which is probably just a typo)

Comment: There's no general way to do this. As far as HTTP and PHP are concerned, the page exists, it just contains text saying that you made a mistake. You can collect a list of strings that appear on pages like this, and search the output for them.

Comment: It's entirely up to the sending server to put in an appropriate HTTP status code. If the server lies about a missing file and sends a 200, then there's nothing you can do to detect that.

Comment: It is very difficult to do because the messages are different

Comment: You probably want to check the `Content-Type`.

Comment: I'm thinking to take the error message of each page and ask them where the server 200 in response me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will have to search webpage for specific not found word as most sites will not give a 404 code.

```
function chk_error($a)
{
        // list of error messages
    $file_error = array("This file does not exist", "File Not Found"); 

    foreach($file_error as $v){

    $findme = strrpos($a, $v);  
    if ($findme === false) {
    $err = 1;
} else {
    $err = 2; break;
}
    }
    return $err;
}



$ch = curl_init("http://dfiles.eu/files/r0flcxpwp");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$page_content = curl_exec($ch);
$url_status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

if ("404" == $url_status) {
    echo "do something";
}
elseif(chk_error($page_content)==2){
    echo "do something";
}
else
{
    echo ":)";
    }

curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Thanks, something else, I can do I take multiple url in a loop some example that can show me that?

Comment: you just make the curl code a function and pass  it through a loop. [demo](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/0hm-i6p)

Comment: All right, I'll compare with mine to see what mistake I made. Thanks!